# Why does AppHarbor + RequireHttpsAttribute equal frowny-face :(

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, https, appharbor, requirehttps

First deployment to AppHarbor today. After some initial work getting it to build, I successfully deployed an MVC3 app.

There is a problem with using the RequireHttpsAttribute though. I noticed at first that http pages were working fine, but https pages were getting the error that the web page has a redirect loop.

I have been meaning to require https for the entire app, so I went and added a global RequireHttpsAttribute filter in global.asax. Now every single page is getting the redirect loop error, in chrome and FF.

Assume this has something to do with port redirecting behind the scenes. How to fix it? Do I need a custom RequireHttpsAttribute?

Comment: I didn't know that the problem is caused by requirehttpsattribute, I just got an endless redirect 302 loop. Firefox said the problem may be caused by cookie, which led me to the wrong direction. Fortunately I had an idea to browse the appharbor tag and found this post. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answers [here](http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/401-requirehttps-attribute-doesnt-work-in-aspnet-mvc3-on-appharbor) and [here](https://gist.github.com/915869). A custom RequireHttpsAttribute override was necessary.

Comment: Another option here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510037/https-with-url-rewriting-is-not-working-on-appharbor/18922822#18922822